# get position of the elements from list Array

Tags: scala

Hi I am trying to get 2nd position and 4th position of elements from the below list array. Can someone guide me how to get it from below list

`List[Array[String]] = List(Array(111, 1, 333, 100), Array(112, 2, 222, 505), Ar
0), Array(117, 1, 444, 540), Array(118, 1, 666, 4400), Array(119, 3, 333, 3300), Array
00))`

**The expected result should be**

`List((1,100), (2,505), (3,510), (4,600), (1,510), (1,520), (1,540), (1,4400), (3,3300), (1,1500), (1,2500), (3,4500), (1,1100))`

Comment: What have you tried? Why it did not worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution that uses `map`:

```
 yourList.map(_.toList) // 1.
  .map  {
    case _::b::_::d::_ => b::d::Nil // 2.
    case _ => Nil // 3.
  }.filterNot(_.isEmpty) // .4
```

1. change the elements to `List` as they are easy to match.
2. map the element-List with *Pattern Matching*.
3. Handle unexpected cases.
4. Remove the unhandled cases.

This gives you: `List(List(1, 100), List(2, 505), List(1, 540), List(1, 4400), List(3, 3300))`

After your comment (you want to have every 2. element of these Arrays):

```
yourList.map(
   _.grouped(2)   // 1.
    .filter(_.size == 2) // 2.
    .map(_.last) // 3.
    .toList
)
```

1. Create groupes of 2
2. Remove the ones with just one element
3. take only the last of the group

As a further simplification you can use `collect`:

```
yourList.map(
   _.grouped(2)   // 1.
    .collect{ case Seq(_, e) => e} // 2. and 3. in one step
    .toList
)
```

Comment: Thanks pme for your reply. This pattern match is working as per expectation. Suppose if we have more than 20 elements in each array it is difficult to accommodate all these things in case. Is there any other way we can do it. Could you please help me

Comment: see my adjusted answer